# SVG From Python svgwrite not displaying in Ubuntu but does in Windows 7

Tags: linux, python-2.7, svg

I am using the code below to generate a bar code and an SVG graphic using Python 2.7.  On a Windows 7 machine the script executes fine, the SVG files are created and I can view them using Inkscape on Windows.

I can run the code using Ubuntu (with the paths changed) and the script executes without error.  When I try to open the SVG files using Inkscape on Ubuntu, the SVG files draws blank.  If I move the Ubuntu generated files to the Windows machine they look fine.
I am new to Linux-is there something in the code I am missing to close or finalize the SVG files that is not required in Windows or is this just a bug with Ubuntu Inkscape?

```
import sys, traceback
import barcode
import svgwrite
ean = barcode.get('ean8', '16031601')
filename = ean.save('Z:/GISpublic/GerryG/PythonScripts/Barcode/ean8')
options = dict(font_size = 0, module_height = 8, module_width = 1)
filename = ean.save('ean8', options)
#Create the arrowhead in a new svg drawing.
dwg = svgwrite.Drawing('Z:/GISpublic/GerryG/PythonScripts/Barcode/arrowhead.svg')
triangle = dwg.add(dwg.polygon([(280,-15), (280,48),(300,17),(280,-15)], fill='black'))
dwg.save()
```

Comment: I'm a lttile unclear under what circumstances things don't work.

Comment: Updating Inkscape to version 0.92 (from 0.91) seems to have fixed the trouble.  The SVG files look fine under this new release.